# Opposite of 'eyes only'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In secret organisations (at least on TV) there are documents which are marked EYES ONLY meaning that they shouldn't be recorded in any way except for authorised officers to look at them directly.

What is the opposite of this? (e.g. a document which should never be seen by a human but should readily be read and copied by machines, such as the information a machine collects for google ads).

---

My specific case is that I have a file containing data for physics research which I should never look at (so as not to bias myself) but I want the computer to analyse based on a priori parameters. This is called a blinded analysis (for more info, see [here](http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/blinding-and-unblinding-analyses)).

Comment: Can't think of any phrase that applies here. So, Botsonly?

Comment: or *digital only*. See also Internet of Things.

Comment: "For blind analysis only"?  "EYES OFF"? "NO EYES"?

Comment: I was mistaken about my definition for 'eyes only', but I like 'no eyes'. I think I'll use that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Eyes Only" does not mean that it may only be viewed or looked at by human eyes, it is short for "For Your Eyes Only", meaning that it is classified material that may only be read by authorised persons.

Therefore the opposite of "Eyes Only" is "unclassified", i.e. not restricted to authorised personnel only.

So I don't believe the answer to your question is actually what you need and further I am not convinced there is one word to describe material that may not be viewed by humans but may be processed by a machine.